# How to use GridSearchCV with RidgeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm trying to use `GridSearchCV` with `RidgeClassifier`, but I'm getting this error:

My problem is **regression** type.

> IndexError: too many indices for array

I'm new to Machine Learning, please help me out.
This is the code I've been trying to implement:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]
scores = ['precision', 'recall']
alphas = np.array([1,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001,0])
model = RidgeClassifier(normalize=True, random_state=100, tol=0.1)
for score in scores:
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=dict(alpha=alphas))
    clf.fit(X, Y)
    print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
    print(clf.best_params_)
    for params, mean_score, scores in clf.grid_scores_:
        print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
              % (mean_score, scores.std() * 2, params))
```

This is the complete error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-c97c7e0fc6f3> in <module>()
     12 for score in scores:
     13     clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=dict(alpha=alphas))
---> 14     clf.fit(X, Y)
     15     print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
     16     print(clf.best_params_)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    836 
    837         """
--> 838         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    839 
    840 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    551                                  'of samples (%i) than data (X: %i samples)'
    552                                  % (len(y), n_samples))
--> 553         cv = check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    554 
    555         if self.verbose > 0:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier)
   1833         if classifier:
   1834             if type_of_target(y) in ['binary', 'multiclass']:
-> 1835                 cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv)
   1836             else:
   1837                 cv = KFold(_num_samples(y), cv)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in __init__(self, y, n_folds, shuffle, random_state)
    568         for test_fold_idx, per_label_splits in enumerate(zip(*per_label_cvs)):
    569             for label, (_, test_split) in zip(unique_labels, per_label_splits):
--> 570                 label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]
    571                 # the test split can be too big because we used
    572                 # KFold(max(c, self.n_folds), self.n_folds) instead of

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: what do you get for `X.shape` and `Y.shape`?

Comment: @DavidMarx  (15780, 24) (15780, 1) , these are their respective shapes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Y has shape `(15780,1)`. The shape of Y should show `(15780,)`. The explanation for this is a bit long, so I just give here the links-

[Difference between shapes (R,1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

[Solution for IndexError: too many indices for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995175/scikit-learn-cross-val-score-too-many-indices-for-array)

Comment: How do I change this `(15780, 1)` to `(15780, )` ?

Comment: I replaced `Y` with `Y.ravel()` and got this error >AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Try- `Y = Y.reshape(15780,)`. It should solve the problem.